# Upload docx, pdf, jpg file to cloudinary

Tags: javascript, react-native, cloudinary

Hello everyone I am currently working on the ReactNative mobile application.

I am trying to upload files to Cloudinary but I get the following error.

`{"error": {"message": "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"}}`

It says that the upload preset should be specified but I had already done in my code.

```js
let data =  new FormData()
data.append('upload_preset','my preset name')
data.append('file', uri)
data.append('cloud_name', 'my could name')
    
fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/Cloud_name/image/upload', {
    method:'post',
    body: {
        data
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

can anyone help me to figure out what went wrong?
Or is there any better way that I can upload my files in the cloud?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload preset as described here [Preset Configuration](https://res.cloudinary.com/orlyborly/video/upload/preset_configuration.mp4)

Then you can add it to your upload call:

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your upload preset is set as 'unsigned'.

Here is a sample code in React if it helps:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-forked-eskni?file=/src/index.js

(set your cloud name and preset where needed)